# boost smart pointer can cast but std cant?

Tags: python, c++, pybind11

I'm working on a quite old code that has some functions that return an allocated raw pointer (here an oversimplication of what the function does):

```
MyClass* func(){
    MyClass* myPtr = new MyClass();
    return myPtr;
}
```

I want to bind this class and the function that returns the pointer into python using pybind11:

The class:

```
py::class_<MyClass>(m, "PyClass")
// Methods and atributes ...
```

The function (?):

```
m.def("get_object", &func);
```

This compiles and works the first time I launch it, however it crashes afterwards. I thought it's because the allocated object was never de-allocated, so I tried (with no success) using smart pointers and setting the return policy:

```
m.def("get_object_smart", [](){
        auto a = std::unique_ptr<MyClass>(func());
        return a;
    }, py::return_value_policy::copy); // also tried take_ownership
```

Is there a way of telling pybind11 when to call the objects destructor? is it different when allocated in the heap with `new`?

Comment: Why do you think that the crash was caused but the object not being deallocated? Not destroying things very rarely causes problems (beyond memory leaks).

Answer (score 1):

According to the docs: https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced/functions.html#return-value-policies

Your original raw pointer will be cleaned up by Python's garbage collector, since the return value policy is `return_value_policy::take_ownership`

This is okay, in your instance, since there is no way to delete that instance outside of the function. (Unless of course you do something weird like set a static variable in your C++ program with it).

However, if you do want to manage the lifetime within your C++ program, you could use the following return value policy: `return_value_policy::reference`. Be careful not to reference the variable in python after you have deleted it in C++, that is undefined behaviour.

Another interesting idea is to supply a custom deleter to your `std::unique_ptr`. Something like this:

```
auto customDeleter = [](MyClass* myClass) { myClass->deleteWhenIwant(); };

m.def("get_object_smart", [] {
        return std::unique_ptr<MyClass, decltype(customDeleter)> b(new MyClass, customDeleter);
    });
```

This would leave Python to decide when clean up the object, but you would decide the mechanism that it uses.